# Is it possible to make Symfony ignore a double slash in the URL

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm writing a new endpoint for 3rd party desktop application, and there are several different functions in the application that post to the same endpoint on my Symfony 2.8 server.

Sometimes the desktop application goes to the correct path - `example.com/path/to/endpoint`. However sometimes it tries to go to add an extra slash in between the domain name and the path - `example.com//path/to/endpoint`.

I tried to just add an extra route with the double slash in it like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/path/to/route", name="example_route")
 * @Route("//path/to/route", name="example_route_double_slash")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
```

Symfony just ignores the double slash when it compiles the routes though, and I end up with 2 of "/path/to/route" if I check my routes with `app/console debug:router`

Comment: Not exactly the answer to your question, but to fix the underlying issue you may want to take a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1511414

Comment: I don't think this is the quite direction I'm looking to go... It looks like the issue discussed in this link was fixed on php-5.5.17 and I'm on php 5.6.19 on Ubuntu for my production server, and php 5.6.22 on my mac for development. Both aren't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By default, the Symfony Routing component requires that the parameters
>   match the following regex path: [^/]+. This means that all characters
>   are allowed except /.
>
> You must explicitly allow / to be part of your parameter by specifying
>   a more permissive regex path.

Your route definition have to use regex :

```
 /**
 * @Route("/{slash}/path/to/route", name="example_route_double_slash", requirements={"slash"="\/?"})
 */
```

I haven't tested the code but it basically says that you are adding an extra parameter that may or may not be a `/`.

The code snippet is inspired from this one at official docs :

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DemoController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/hello/{username}", name="_hello", requirements={"username"=".+"})
     */
    public function helloAction($username)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

find more here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html